# Zybook 4.17 LAB: Flip a coin (EOF while parsing error)

Tags: python

I am having an issue with my code where I am continuously getting the error `EOF while reading a line`. This is the only error I am having. The first test works fine, the following tests that are labeled unit test are failing with the EOF error.

Here is my code

```
import random

def heads_or_tails():
      number_of_flips = int(input())
      for i in range(0, number_of_flips):
        
        flip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if (flip == 0):
          print("heads")
        else:
          print("tails")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        random.seed(1)
        heads_or_tails()
```

I have tried both putting the input code within the code block an beneath the `__name__ == '__main__` line.

[These are the test conditions, I am required to keep the input statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPsT0.png)

Comment: You have to run the code from a text mode console in order to be able to type in the input.

Comment: Please edit your question so the title will describe your problem, because "some lab flip a coin" is very poor description.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF while reading a line.` is recieved when no input is given to `input()`.

In your tests you should pass a default value (depending on the actual unit-test and what you are trying to check) instead of asking for input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def heads_or_tails():
    # Type your code here. 
    flip = random.randint(0,1)
    if(flip == 0):
        flip = 'heads'
    else:
        flip = 'tails'
    return flip


if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed(1)
    number_of_flips = int(input())

    # Type your code here. 
    for n in range(number_of_flips):
        print(heads_or_tails())
```

#you must let the function return the string 'heads' or 'tails'
#and the for loop should not be in the function.